# Where does secure-session store session data?

Tags: fastify, fastify-cookie

I've started using `@fastify/secure-session` in my app, and I can't find anything on the docs to say where it's storing data. I was planning to use redis, but it's not using that (yet). It can't be in memory as restarting the app doesn't lose the session data. Can anyone tell me where it is?

```
import fastifyCookie from '@fastify/cookie'
import fp from 'fastify-plugin'
import secureSession from '@fastify/secure-session'
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

export const sessionPlugin = fp(async (app, options, next) => {
    app.register(secureSession, {
        // the name of the attribute decorated on the request-object, defaults to 'session'
        sessionName: 'session',
        // the name of the session cookie, defaults to value of sessionName
        cookieName: 'my-session',
        // adapt this to point to the directory where secret-key is located
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(config.root, 'secret-key')),
        cookie: {
            domain: 'mydomain.com',
            path: '/'
            // options for setCookie, see https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cookie
        }
    })

    app.addHook('onRequest', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.cookies) // shows my-session cookie
    })
})
```

Comment: it is written in the config: the browser's cookie

Comment: Cna I change that to redis?

Comment: I have just looked into using @fastify/secure-session (as a required part of @fastify/passport) and from the documentation says, the difference is that secure-session stores the entire session in a highly secure cookie (similar to a JWT) whereas @fastify/session stores the session information in the more traditional manner of a key-value (noSQL) store such as Redis/DyanmoDB etc. I am still researching this but, if this is the case, I might rework @fastify/passport to remove this dependency.